# Winapi error 1812

Tags: c++, winapi

I am trying to create a modeless dialog box, but the CreateDialog function fails with an error **0x714** or **1812** base10.

```
m_StatusHwnd = CreateDialog( hInstance,
                            MAKEINTRESOURCE( IDD_STATUSWND ),
                            0,
                            DXCore::statusWindProc );

// Check:
if ( m_StatusHwnd == NULL )
{
    string s = std::to_string( GetLastError( ) );
    MessageBox( 0, s.c_str( ), "Status Window init FAILED", MB_OK );
    return false;
}
```

I created the resource in VS2013. I made sure to include the resource header file. But the error code implies that the resource is not found or compiled : I found this on microsofts developer site :

```
ERROR_RESOURCE_DATA_NOT_FOUND 
1812 (0x714)
The specified image file did not contain a resource section.
```

on further research I discovered that it might be required to create a modeless class for this to work, but I ca't find any tutorials or descriptions of how.

Can you please point me in a direction?

Comment: Make sure the value in `hInstance` refers to the correct module.

Comment: You have to add the RC file to the project. The header file merely says that resources exist. You also need to add the resources.

Comment: The dialog func (4th parameter to CreateDialog) must be a static function. Are you trying to use a non-static member function?

Comment: thank you for all those responses: The RC file is included in the project and solution. To ScottMcP: the DXCore::statusWindProc is declared like so:  static BOOL CALLBACK statusWindProc( ... ) and it captures the application pointer, sending it to a class pointer running the application.

@Captain Obvlious: Please tell me what you mean. Of this I know nothing. is hInstance not supposed to be the application instance handle? it is forwarded all the way from WinMain.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was inspired by @Captain Obvlious. Instead of hInstance in the first parameter of CreateDialog, I passed NULL and the function succeeded - the window showed like supposed to.

```
m_StatusHwnd = CreateDialog( NULL,
                             MAKEINTRESOURCE( IDD_STATUSWND ),
                             0,
                             DXCore::statusWindProc );
```

from msdn.microsoft.com: "hInstance: A handle to the module which contains the dialog box template. If this parameter is NULL, then the current executable is used."

Comment: Better than passing `NULL` is to pass the instance handle of the executable. It is passed to your `WinMain` function. Passing `NULL` means that this code can never be moved into a DLL.

Comment: I thought so too - but this does not work - unfortunately. The createDialog function fails if I try to..

Comment: Then something else is wrong. What is the value of `hInstance` when your `WinMain` receives it? What is the value of `hInstance` when you call `CreateDialog`? The two should be equal. If not, then something got lost in the chain of custody.

Comment: I Just checked. They are both 0x7efde000 every time I run the application.

Comment: `0x7efde000` doesn't look right. Maybe you declared `WinMain` incorrectly. What does `GetModuleHandle(NULL)` return?